# Uncover proof after itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'd like to have a proof in the same frame as an itemize. If I write

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->] 
\item Point One
\item Point Two 
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

Then what happens is that the frame starts with Proof visible. Then it produces (in this case) 3 slides each with Proof visible and the 3 slides corresponding to the one by one itemize. What I'd like is to treat Proof as a 4th item appearing as a 4th slide. (So the 3rd slide has all itemize points and the 4th slide has all itemize points plus proof underneath.)

I've tried \only and \uncover on Proof but they don't seem to work. I CAN use \pause before \begin{proof} but this duplicates the final itemize slide (giving 5 slides instead of 4). This is practically feasible but I was just wondering for the future if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using `\uncover<4->{}` for the proof environment works for me:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->] 
\item Point One
\item Point Two 
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\uncover<4->{%
\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the {% syntax for applying the uncover onto the proof. It just had some weird interaction that made no sense.

Comment: There's nothing special in `{%`. It's just a comment to ignore space which LaTeX inserts at the end of lines. In this case all that matters is a pair of braces around the proof.